# Creating WIN32 application (Object Oriented) (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

I cant seem to figure out what is problem here. The error is highlighted under `hInstance`

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "WindowApp.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG Msg;
    LPCTSTR ClsName = "Win32OOP";
    LPCTSTR WndName = "Object-Oriented Win32 Programming";

    // Initialize the application class
    Game WinApp(hInstance, ClsName, MainWndProc); // Error here. Screenshot below
    WinApp.RegWndClass();

    // Create the main window
    WindowApp Wnd;
    Wnd.Create(hInstance, ClsName, WndName); 
    Wnd.Show();

    // Process the main window's messages
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Here is the Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#define Win32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
// Include the basic windows header file
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h> 

class Game
{
    // Global variable that holds the application
    WNDCLASSEX _WndClsEx;

public:
    Game();
    // This constructor will initialize the application
    Game(HINSTANCE hInst, char *ClasName,WNDPROC WndPrc, LPCTSTR MenuName = NULL);
    // Class Registration
    void RegWndClass();
    ~Game();
};

#endif
```

[image]

Here is the link that i refer to : http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson06.htm

Comment: does char * == LPCTSTR && WNDPROC == LPCTSTR?

Comment: @Kupto http://postimg.org/image/e74favwzn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you pass `HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR, WNDPROC` to `Game` constructor. But it expects `HINSTANCE, char *, WNDPROC`. T`LPCTSTR` is not the same as `char*`.

Simply change the signature of `Game` constructor to `Game(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR, WNDPROC)`.

Comment: I would rather than changing the constructor recommend changing the data you put into it... this will save you more trouble in the long-run...

Comment: @Kupto Huh? I don't see how manipulating a long string is any harder than manipulating a narrow string. Both are accomplished using abominable, error-prone, security-nightmare producing C APIs. At least with the wide string you know the encoding.

Comment: @KubaOber I am not saying that what you wrote is wrong... it is 100% valid solution. What I am saying is that perhaps you should recommend the oop beginner to rather change the "outside of the class code" first... especially changing the prototypes of public member methods should be the last thing to do... (just my opinion)

Comment: @Kupto You claim it will "save more trouble". I don't see the trouble it will save and claim that using narrow strings is more error prone, in fact, because you can easily slip on assuming an encoding that isn't.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for the guide. I played it around and changed the constructor to like what you suggested and in the Game.cpp i changed to this `Game::Game(HINSTANCE hInst, LPCTSTR ClsName,WNDPROC WndPrc/*, LPCTSTR MenuName*/)
{` Now it is working :)

Comment: @KubaOber my opinion simply is that you should not advice beginner to mess with public member prototypes, unless the problem can be resolved otherwise. The key thing in creating OOP structure is abstraction, once the public constructor signatures are declared (what should be done after deep thought), they should not be EVER touched. Better solution would be to create new constructor that takes arguments you need, NOT changing the constructor you already have, because you never know who or what else relies on them. It is only problem of semantics of learning OOP though, what you proposed is OK.

Comment: Kuba: *"At least with the wide string you know the encoding."* Except, `LPCTSTR` is **not** a wide character string. If you wish to use the wide character version, it is `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: @IInspectable With `_UNICODE` defined, `TCHAR` is typedef's as `wchar_t`, so LPCTSTR is a wide string, right? I presume that having `_UNICODE` defined is a SOP these days?

Comment: @Kupto All pieces of this are designed with equal amount of thought. It's an early student project. Don't overthink it :)

Comment: This is not about SOP's. It's about types and intents. If you wish to use a wide character string, `LPCWSTR` it is. `LPCTSTR` may or may not be. It is a different type alias, and it is there to address a different scenario. Do not promote Code-By-Coincidence. Plus, using wide character strings tells you **nothing** about the encoding. Welcome to C++.

Comment: @IInspectable You are right, of course, but in real life wide strings are either UTF-16 (or UCS-2) or UTF-32/UCS-4. The UTF-16 vs. UCS-2 brouhaha surely is something that could derail a couple of things. So, I take it back that LPCTSTR is wide. It's still OK to use it here, though :) Of course it's got nothing to do with C++ at all... it's C APIs all the way down :)

Comment: I was referring to `wchar_t`, which is defined in the C++ Standard. The way it is defined explicitly allows for arbitrary encodings, even non-standard ones. The encoding is allowed to change between different locales as well. In other words: Using a `wchar_t` tells you **nothing** about the encoding. And this **is** C++.